# How to generate random numbers? First and last number has to be the same

Tags: c#, random

I need to generate 10 different numbers(integers). My problem is that the first and last number has to be the same. How can I make a code for this logic?
The numbers are later used to populate a polar chart.

```
Random random = new Random();

int randomNumber = random.Next(5, 16);
int firstRand = 0;
firstRand = randomNumber;

if(indataInt2 == 0)
{
    firstRand = randomNumber;
}
else if(indataInt2 >= 360 && firstRand != randomNumber)
{
    randomNumber = firstRand;
}
```

Comment: Generate **9** such numbers and assign 10th to 1st

Comment: Just generate 9 different numbers, find out what the first one is, add that to the end.

Comment: What is the range of the numbers (1-10? 1-100?)? Why not just generate 9 numbers, and then use the first number as the 10th number?

Comment: I'm obviously doing something wrong....

Comment: If the first and tenth numbers are always the same, then they are not strictly random.  You have nine random numbers and one fully determined number.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should do the job

```
        List<int> randomNumber = new List<int>();
        Random random = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {
            randomNumber.Add(random.Next());
        }

        randomNumber.Add(randomNumber[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

> First things first, when using the Random class you can provide a seed in 
>   which will specify how the number is generated. Therefore I provided
>   a seed for you. This seed is always changing so the random number will 
>   always be different. Remember, Random isn't Random, Random(Seed)
>   is Random! The list in which you are looking for is named 'Numbers'.
>
> **Hopefully this code can help you:**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;

namespace Degubbing
{
    class DebugProgram
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<int> Numbers = new List<int> { };

            int Seed = DateTime.Now.Millisecond;
            Random Generator = new Random(Seed);

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                int RandomNum = Generator.Next(10000000, 20000000);
                string Result = RandomNum.ToString();
                Result = Result.Remove(Result.Length - 1);
                Result = Result + Result[0];
                Console.WriteLine(Result);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```